# warning: converting to non-pointer type 'int' from NULL

Tags: c++, return

I need to write a dictionary in c++
There is a function that returns the value of a dictionary by key, but if there is no value, then I want to return something like NULL. The value 0 is not suitable because it could be the value of some other key.
What can i use instead of 0?

```
TValue getByKey(TKey key)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->pairs.size(); i++)
    {
        if (this->pairs[i].key == key)
            return this->pairs[i].value;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

if I use NULL it gives me a warning (g++ compiler):

```
warning: converting to non-pointer type 'int' from NULL
```

Comment: `int` is not nullable. You can pick a different type like `std::optional<int>` or pick a special value that means "no result" like `npos` for `std::string` or use a different strategy like returning an iterator instead or you can `throw` if the value is not found (if this is not expected to happen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is specifically a value for pointers. If the object that you return is not a pointer (or a smart pointer), then returning `NULL` is wrong.

If you return an `int`, then you can only return a value that `int` can represent, i.e. 0 or 1 or 2 ...

If you want to return a value that represents "no value", then you can return instance of `std::optional` template instead. Example:

```
std::optional<TValue> getByKey(TKey key)
{
    // ...

    return std::nullopt;
}
```

---

P.S. You can replace your loop that implements linear search with the standard function `std::find`.

P.P.S If you have many values, then may want to consider using another data structure that has faster key lookup such as `std::unordered_map`.

P.P.P.S Don't use `NULL` for pointers either. It has been obsoleted by `nullptr`.

Comment: `std::optional` is a great solution. In the old days before it was invented, it was common to reserve an unused value like -1 and return that instead.